# show HTML in alert window same like iframe?

Tags: javascript, html

i want to show HTML in alert window same like iframe..? can i do this...

```
<script>
alert("<html><body><h1>this is alert heading</h1></html></body>")
</script>
```

how can i do this..?

Comment: You can't, javascript alert doesn;t support html. try looking at this questions and see the answer, it uses sort of you idea.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10665746/timer-with-interval-alert/10665865#10665865

Comment: what if you put iframe inside? not sure if you can though..

Comment: @Andres Uh, no, you can't put an iframe inside an alert().

Comment: @ceejayoz you're right I was still half asleep lol

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Instead of using alert, I would use a Pop Up. And I recommend you to use something like jQuery Dialog , look at http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/

Sample :

First, create a div to wrap your html elements,

```
<div id='my-dialog-id' title='my dialog title'>
  <h1>this is alert heading</h1>
</div>
```

Then include some javascript with jQuery and jQueryUI

```
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <script>
  $(function() {
    $("#my-dialog-id").dialog(); //Here I select a div with id my-dialog-id and start the plugin.
  } );
  </script>
```

And it's ready!

Answer (score 7):

If your asking how to display the HTML markup per se in the alert box, escape it:

```
alert("\<html\>\<body\>\<h1\>this is alert heading\</h1\>\</html\>\</body\>")
```

If you are asking how to format the alert box using HTML you cannot.  You need to create a modal dialog box as one of the other answers indicates.

Answer (score 4):

You can't do it via `alert()`.

You can mimic it using a modal dialog. There are lots of modal dialog libraries - [jQuery UI](http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/) has a pretty powerful one.

Comment: can i call HTML with id in alert box??

Comment: Can you rephrase that? Didn't make any sense.