# How to add HTML markup to a specific place in a string?

Tags: javascript

So I am given a sentence, and in the middle of the sentence there will be "`_`". At the "`_`" I want to replace it with `<span class="smallBox"></span>` so that I can insert a box at that point.

```
var string = "This is a string_right here";
var here = string.replace("_","<span class="smallBox"></span>");

alert(here);
```

However what is alerted is: `This is a string<span class="smallBox"></span>right here`;

Can someone help?

Comment: Well, that's exactly what you've told it to do, and what your requirements say it should do. What's wrong?

Comment: NB: you have a syntax error in your JavaScript : fix the quotes.

Comment: i dn think you can render html inside alert box.. if that is what you are looking at..

Comment: Possible duplicate of [show HTML in alert window same like iframe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10689556/show-html-in-alert-window-same-like-iframe)

Answer (score 1):

Nope, there is no way to interpret HTML tags using `alert()`, since it is a method of the window object. You could use something like [JQueryUI Dialog](http://jqueryui.com/dialog/) to emulate an alert box, but if you *really* need an actual one, the only thing you can do that is even *close* to the behavior you want is printing out unicode characters, newlines, and tabs. For example:

```js
// Warning: Unicode madness ahead
alert(
  'Alert with newlines, tabs, and bullet points\n' +
  '■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■\n' +
  "\t■ Meaningless Point #1\n" +
  '\t■ Meaningless Point #2\n' +
  '\t■ Meaningless Point #3\n' +
  '■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■\n'
);
```

Alert boxes really weren't meant to do much and this is probably the best you can expect from one.

Answer (score -1):

At first, escape the quotes around smallBox:

```
var here = string.replace("_","<span class=\"smallBox\"></span>");
```

Then the output will be: **This is a string<span class="smallBox"></span>right here**
Because using alert will print your HTML as String.

Comment: So that is what the OP also had as output? What is the additional value?